# Unique representation of constructible numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

I am interested in programmatically working with constructible numbers (the closure of the rational numbers under square roots). In order to perform comparisons between numbers I believe I would need a unique (symbolic) representation for them. Does such a thing exist, or what are relevant references for this kind of thing?

Comment: When you say "comparison" do you mean "test for equality" or are you trying to determine if one is greater than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A representation of construcible numbers together with algorithms suitable for mechanized computations is given in chapter 4 of [these lecture notes on computer science](http://books.google.com/books?id=nX9En3pwqWsC&pg=PA279&lpg=PA279&dq=representation+of+constructible+numbers&source=bl&ots=2BWAueNw41&sig=mGPSlh0ltREnq6DitnbAhxSSxoY&hl=en&ei=yRs7S53mEommnQObz4TuCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CAoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=representation%2520of%2520constructible%2520numbers&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that there is no nice way to compare constructible numbers. The [sum of square roots problem](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P33.html) is notoriously difficult, as an example of difficulties you might be facing. The link has relevant references I believe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784901/can-coordinates-of-constructable-points-be-represented-exactly is also relevant depending on what you are interested.